# Serving Django 1.7 application using CherryPy

Tags: python, django, cherrypy

I'm trying to serve a Django 1.7 application using CherryPy. The startup script is as follows:

```
import wsgiserver
import sys
import os
import django.core.handlers.wsgi


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))  # add django project absolute path
    # Startup Django
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8001), django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
try:
    server.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Stopping'
    server.stop()
```

Everything is setup okay. However, when i try accessing the application(the django success page) I get an error:

```
AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

Reading around, I found that you run the migrations before runserver and also add django.setup() to wsgi.py. Sadly that solution does not work for me.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Django 1.7 imports all the models files at setup time. If you do something in your models that relies on the setup having happened already (like non-lazy gettext, which needs to know the current language), that fails with that error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the correct solution, but I was able to resolve this problem in my own code by inserting

```
django.setup()
```

immediately after the call to define the settings module.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by running django.setup() after the imports in wsgiserver2.py.